# Can I automatically populate `created_at` timestamp to transaction timestamp with Google Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-spanner

I am looking through the documentation for Google Cloud Spanner, and it looks like write operations return a timestamp when the row was actually written.

But when reading rows, it doesn't seem possible to re-capture that timestamp (either as a column that can be read or as a column that could be limited and sorted on).

I assume that I could just update the row after it is written to append a new column (`created_at`), but ideally it would be nice to have that field automatically appended.

Is there any way to access the original transaction timestamp when querying spanner? I also noticed that there was a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` sql function. Is that equivalent to the transaction timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create commit timestamp columns, and Cloud Spanner writes the timestamp as part of the transaction:

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/commit-timestamp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; [consider what would happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, updating the timestamp column is the closest we can get.

Answer (score 0):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` returns the current time.

See for more information:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#current_timestamp